# Ideas on incorrect ORDER BY results

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I want to emphasize that I'm looking for ideas, not necessarily a concrete answer since it's difficult to show what my queries look like, but I don't believe that's needed.

The process looks like this:

1. Table A keeps filling up, like a bucket - an SQL job keeps calling SP_Proc1 every minute or less and it inserts multiple records into table A.
2. At the same time a C# process keeps calling another procedure SP_Proc2 every minute or less that **does an ordered TOP 5 select from table A and returns the results** to the C# method. After C# code finishes processing the results it deletes the selected 5 records from table A.

I bolded the problematic part above. It is necessary that the records from table A be processed 5 at a time in the order specified, but a few times a month SP_Proc2 selects the ordered TOP 5 records in a wrong order even though all the records are present in table A and have correct column values that are used for ordering.

Something to note:

- I'm ordering by integers, not varchar.
- The C# part is using 1 thread.
- Both SP_Proc1 and SP_Proc2 use a transaction and use READ COMMITTED OR READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT transaction isolation level.
- One column that is used for ordering is a computed value, but a very simple one. It just checks if another column in table A is not null and sets the computed column to either 1 or 0.
- There's a unique nonclustered index on primary key Id and a clustered index composed of the same columns used for ordering in SP_Proc2.
- I'm using SQL Server 2012 (v11.0.3000)

I'm beginning to think that this might be an SQL bug or maybe the records or index in table A get corrupted and then deleted by the C# process and that's why I can't catch it.

Edit:

To clarify, SP_Proc1 commits a big batch of N records to table A at once and SP_Proc2 pulls the records from table A in batches of 5, it orders the records in the table and selects TOP 5 and sometimes a wrong batch is selected, the batch itself is ordered correctly, but a different batch was supposed to be selected according to ORDER BY. I believe [Rob Farley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64426231/14477443) might have the right idea.

Comment: An `ORDER BY` isn't ignored; which means that the likely hood is that you are misunderstanding something, or the process is flawed. Honestly, without any code, I would guess the latter.

Comment: On a different note, why are you running SQL Server 2012 SP1? Why haven't you updated in 8 years (SP1 came out in November 212)?

Comment: SQL Server is multi-threaded and does not store data in order.  So when you do a query you always need top do an orderby to get the data in correct order.  Now when you are using top you  are getting the top at the moment you query is run and may change a moment after the query has run.  So if you want to delete the same top five items you must remove by using a WHERE which uniquely identifies the five tiems you want removed.

Comment: _think that this might be an SQL bug_ Nope - as a programmer you should always suspect that your own code is the source of the problem. And there are many discussions of using a table as a queue - that's probably a good starting point.

Comment: "*think that this might be an SQL bug"* Even if it *was* you're using a version that is 8 years old; the first step would therefore be to install the last 8 years worth of updates.

Comment: What do you mean by *"SP_Proc2 selects the ordered TOP 5 records in a wrong order"*? Is it that it gets the correct top 5, but they are in the wrong order? (For example, you insert them into a temp table, but TOP 1 from that temp table doesn't align with what you need?) If that is the case, ensure the SP sorts and takes the correct records rather than relying on them being in the correct order in the select/table.

Comment: You need to show some code. This type of thing is easy to get wrong but without any code we can't say where it is wrong

Comment: @seanb I edited the post and added an clarification at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your “out of order TOP 5” is ordered, but that a later five overlaps. Like, one time you get 1231, 1232, 1233, 1234, and 1236, and the next batch is 1235, 1237, and so on.

This can be an issue with locking and blocking. You’ve indicated your processes use transactions, so it wouldn’t surprise me if your 1235 hasn’t been committed yet, but can just be ignored by your snapshot isolation, and your 1236 can get picked up.

It doesn’t sound like there’s a bug here. What I’m describing above is a definite feature of snapshot isolation. If you must have 1235 picked up in an earlier batch than 1236, then don’t use snapshot isolation, and force your table to be locked until each block of inserts is finished.

Comment: I think you're on to something. To clarify, SP_Proc1 commits a big batch of N records to table A at once (up to 5000) and SP_Proc2 pulls the records from table A in batches of 5, it first orders the records and then selects TOP 5 and sometimes a wrong batch is selected. I'm still not sure how SNAPSHOT could be at play here, but I will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative suggestion would be to use a table lock (tablock) for the reading and writing procedures.

Though this is expensive, if you desire absolute consistency then this may be the way to go.